# Why does my gradle download sources by default?

Tags: gradle

I converted my maven project to gradle with `gradle init`. Now every time I import the same project into my IDE, gradle downloads the same dependencies from the scratch, and what's worse is it also downloads the sources, I have no idea where that was configured, I am using IntelliJ, but I didn't configure anything related to gradle. How can I let gradle cache the same dependencies and not download sources?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the gradle related files (i.e. build.gradle, settings.gradle and gradle.properties) created by calling `gradle init`?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable downloading sources in your Gradle config file when using 'idea' plugin. See: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html (search for 'downloadSources').